# get same value issue in list view from String Array in Android

Tags: java, android

***I have problem when i get value from two or more String Array in list view i get only first String Array in list view using different button Click List value are coming from array th list is not getting different value  in list***

//Here is my code using switch case

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class CategoriesList extends ListActivity {
    ListView listView;
    private String[] name1;
    private static int[] name = { R.array.NewArrivals, R.array.Sarees,
            R.array.SalwarKameez, R.array.Lahenga, R.array.Kurti,
            R.array.Jewelry, R.array.Accessories, R.array.ReadyToShip };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.itemlist);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        displayList();
    }

    public void displayList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 1; i <= name.length; i++) 
        {
                name1 = getResources().getStringArray(name[i]);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, name1);
                setListAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you overwrite the adatper you set in one iteration in the next one? You are setting all the adapters to the same list item, meaning that just the last setting will have visual effect (all the others will be overriden).

Maybe you need to change the ids of the list items for the different cases?

As you have written your code now you do not need to have `switch` in the `for` you can rewrite your code like that:

```
String [] name1;
for (int i = 0; i <= name.length; i++) {
    name1 = getResources().getStringArray(name[i]);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
       new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, name1);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
}
```

Though, once again, this is not what you intended, I suppose.

Comment: Ok.. i got it.. but the i have overloaded the adapter because i want to set the method of Adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true).

Comment: i used your code sir but i did not get list. it displaying error sir.

Comment: @SulabhGajjar: which code you mean? Maybe you got me wrong? The code I posted was not a suggestion for you, just illustration of what you exactly do. I can not advise you of how exactly to implement your things until it gets clear what you are aiming to achieve.

Comment: yaa.. Sir i want to get data in common list. When i click on any button the different different data will come from the String array items which is statically set in String Array..

Comment: @SulabhGajjar then shouldn't `displayList` receive as parameter the list that must be shown? what error do you receive by using my examplary code?

Answer (score 0):

Function `displayList()` always ends up setting list adapter to display the elements from `R.array.ReadyToShip`. This is not what you wanted?

Comment: i want to string array from string on different button click i want to show different data which are store in String array so how is it possible.

Comment: You can create and array of strings like { "New Arrivals", "Sarees", ... } and display it using ArrayAdapter. Then in onListItemClicked you get the position of a clicked topic, determine which another array shall be shown and set your arrayadapter accordingly so it gets displayed. In this new 'details' array if anything clicked in your onListItemClick you set your 'topics' array back again

Comment: But sir i dont want to displaty array list on listitem click i want to display data in one common list view while click on different button.\

Comment: Well, you should first aggregate all your data somehow in one list then display that list...